# Merging two files

Tags: join

I would like to merge two files.

file1

```
C       45      897
E       76      348
G       78      456
```

file 2

```
A       54      987
B       34      986
C       67      340
E       46      987
F       34      567
```

should be merged into file 3 as below.

```
A       0       0       54      987
B       0       0       34      986
C       45      897     67      340
E       76      348     46      987
F       0       0       34      567
G       78      456     0       0
```

Answer (score 2):

man join, and a few try

```
join -e 0 -a 1 a b
A 0 0 54 987
B 0 0 34 986
C 45 897 45 897 67 340
E 76 348 76 348 46 987
F 0 0 34 567
G 78 456 78 456 0 0
```

- `-e 0` fill missing column
- `-a 2` keep data from file 1

Answer (score 1):

Store each line of letter-values in a hashed array (%L), with each record being a 4-element array.  After all files have been read, set each undefined value to 0 and print out the array for each letter in %L.

This algorithm scales to more input files (with each extra file increasing the number of columns in the original 4-column array by 2).

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %L=();

my @files = ('file1', 'file2');
my $fcount = 0;

foreach my $f (@files) {
  open(F,"<",$f) || die "couldn't open $f: $!\n";
  while(<F>) {
    my($l, $x, $y) = split;
        $L{$l}[$fcount * 2] = $x;
        $L{$l}[$fcount * 2 + 1] = $y;
  };
  close(F);
  $fcount++;
};

foreach my $l (sort keys %L) {
    foreach (0..3) { $L{$l}[$_] = 0 if !defined($L{$l}[$_])};
    print join("\t",$l,@{ %L{$l} }), "\n";
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
$ ./merge.pl 
A   0   0   54  987
B   0   0   34  986
C   45  897 67  340
E   76  348 46  987
F   0   0   34  567
G   78  456 0   0
```

Answer (score -2):

**Update:** *I misread the question this is not the solution for the given problem*

Should be something like:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort > newfile
```

Probably one could do without cat.

Comment: The question appears to be about joining lines, rather than concatenating them

Comment: This is not waht the OP ask for, for once, neither cat nor sort will generate 0.

Comment: You're right. Misread the problem. I would probably write a short perl skript to achieve the goal.